# Shade multiple peaks with different baselines matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to shade the peaks of multiple graphs that are stacked one above the other. Right now I know how to shade the plot completely (See images) but not how to stablish a "baseline" so that the whole graph is not shaded, only the area below the selected peaks. Could someone help me about how to do it?

Original Graph:
[image: Original graphs]

Example of the desired integration (repeat for all the peaks, not only the maroon one):
[image: Example of the desired integration]

What I can manage to do up to now:
[image]

This is my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib import rcParams

#get file
filepath=r"C:\Users\danie\OneDrive - Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona\uni\PhD\Lubrizol\DSC\Polyesters FDCA 10Kg\FDCAPDO-HDO.xlsx"

#get sheet names
xls=pd.ExcelFile(filepath)
names=xls.sheet_names
nsheet=len(names)
#fonttype
rcParams["font.family"]='sans-serif'
rcParams["font.sans-serif"]="Verdana"

#build figure
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,sharey="all")
#add a counter
counter=0
counter2=0
#start for loop to build the graphs
for i in range(nsheet):
    #get the experiment names
    expname=names[i]
    #build the dataframes for each exp
    df=pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=i)
    #get the temperature column as df
    temp=df["Tr"]
    #create the temp indexes list
    indexes=temp.index.tolist()
    #create the index limit list
    indlist=[]
    #find the limits of each section
    for i in indexes[1:-1]:
        if temp[i-1] - temp[i]>=0 and temp[i]-temp[i+1]<0:
            indlist.append(i)
        elif temp[i-1] - temp[i]<=0 and temp[i]-temp[i+1]>0:
            indlist.append(i)
    #build the heatflow dataframe
    heatflow=df["Heatflow"]
    #build the heatflow dataframe in the desired range
    HFCooling=df["Heatflow"][indlist[1]+30:indlist[2]]
    HFHeating=df["Heatflow"][indlist[2]+30:indlist[3]-10]
    #normalize each of the HF
    HFCooling=(HFCooling-HFCooling.min())/(HFCooling.max()-HFCooling.min())
    HFHeating=(HFHeating-HFHeating.min())/(HFHeating.max()-HFHeating.min())
    #add the counter to HF
    HFCooling=HFCooling + counter
    HFHeating=HFHeating+ counter2
    #build the temperature dataframes in the desired ranges
    TempCooling=df["Tr"][indlist[1]+30:indlist[2]]
    TempHeating=df["Tr"][indlist[2]+30:indlist[3]-10]
    #plot the data
    ax[0].plot(TempCooling, HFCooling, linewidth=2, label=expname)
    ax[0].set_xlim(200,-75)
    ax[0].set_yticks([])
    ax[0].set_ylabel("Heatflow",fontsize=25, labelpad=15)
    ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major',  labelsize=25)
    ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=25)
    ax[0].set_xticks((200,100,0,-70))
    ax[0].fill_between((121,78.9),6.2,7.0)

    ax[1].plot(TempHeating, HFHeating, linewidth=2)
    ax[1].set_xlim(-75,200)
    ax[1].set_yticks([])
    ax[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major',  labelsize=25)
    ax[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=25)
    ax[1].set_xticks((200,100,0,-70))
    #ax[1].set_xlabel("T$\mathregular {^{o}}$C",fontsize=25, labelpad=15)
    #add to the counter 1 loop
    counter=counter+1
    counter2=counter2+1
    if counter==3:
        counter=counter+1


ax[0].text(194,-0.039, "2nd Cooling", fontsize=25)
ax[1].text(-64,-0.039, "2nd Heating", fontsize=25)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.048, right=0.966, top=0.775, bottom=0.162)
fig.text(0.51, 0.04, "T $\mathregular {^{o}}$C", ha='center', fontsize=25)
plt.figlegend(loc='upper center', ncol=3, fontsize=25)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the example of your data has not been provided so I've used simplified test data.

You just need to get the y axis value where  peak starts/ends (you can use average/min/median value or define custom function from them) and use it in the `plt.fill_between()` as arguments.

Possible solution is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# set test data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1 = [5, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 6, 5.5, 5, 5, 5]
y2 = [3, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 4, 3.5, 3, 3, 3]

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=10)
```

**Using average value**

```
def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

plt.fill_between(x, y1, np.array([average(y1)]),
                 where=(y1 >= np.array([average(y1)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='b', interpolate=True)

plt.fill_between(x, y2, np.array([average(y2)]),
                 where=(y2 >= np.array([average(y2)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='r', interpolate=True)

plt.show(f)
```

Returns

[image]

**Using min value**

```
plt.fill_between(x, y1, np.array([min(y1)]),
                 where=(y1 >= np.array([min(y1)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='b', interpolate=True)

plt.fill_between(x, y2, np.array([min(y2)]),
                 where=(y2 >= np.array([min(y2)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='r', interpolate=True)

plt.show(f)
```

Returns

[image]

**Using median value**

```
from statistics import median


plt.fill_between(x, y1, np.array([median(y1)]),
                 where=(y1 >= np.array([median(y1)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='b', interpolate=True)

plt.fill_between(x, y2, np.array([median(y2)]),
                 where=(y2 >= np.array([median(y2)])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='r', interpolate=True)

plt.show(f)
```

Returns

[image]

**Using linear distribution between chart peak start and end**

```
plt.fill_between(x, y1, np.array([5, 5.0, 4.857, 4.71, 4.571, 4.428, 4.285, 4.14, 4.0, 4]),
                 where=(y1 >= np.array([5, 5.0, 4.857, 4.71, 4.571, 4.428, 4.285, 4.14, 4.0, 4])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='b', interpolate=True)

plt.fill_between(x, y2, np.array([3, 3.0, 2.8, 2.65, 2.48, 2.31, 2.14, 1.97, 1.8, 1.8]),
                 where=(y2 >= np.array([3, 3.0, 2.8, 2.65, 2.48, 2.31, 2.14, 1.97, 1.8, 1.8])),
                 alpha=0.30, color='r', interpolate=True)

plt.show(f)
```

Returns

[image]